# Android action bar how to set image in foreground

Tags: android, image, action

I am creating an app on Android 4.0.

I want to display an image in my action bar in foreground along with the app icon and name.

I googled it but found code to set image in background .

I want the image to appear on right of app name and to work in both landscape and portrait orientation.

Any help is greatly appreciated .

Regards
Piyush

Comment: Try this code https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar

Answer (score 0):

You should implement and add a custom `ActionView` to display an image. 
See [this part](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView) of the API Docs on how to do it (it's quite simple actually).